# Query Data in Database by using Robot Framework

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, automated-tests, robotframework

I have queried data in Oracle Database but It cannot be read.

Actual result is `${ValueInDB} = OOP ?????`

Expected result is  `OOP ทดสอบ`

Could you please tell me how to config system to fix this problem?

Remark: ทดสอบ is Thai Language

This is my code

```
Get Data Form Database
    [Arguments]    @{input}
    DatabaseLibrary.Connect To Database Using Custom Params    cx_Oracle    'TEST', 'TEST#', '10.192.168.11:1521/TEST'
    @{resultQuery} =    DatabaseLibrary.Query    @{input}[0]
```

Comment: Can you post how you are Querying the DB? (Like posting some code?)

Comment: Sounds to me like a characterset issue. This might be something that needs to be defined in the SQL session.

Comment: Where are you seeing the `?????` characters - in the console, e.g. `Log To Console` output? If so, it may be just that your console is not capable of displaying them. Robotframework stores all stings as Unicode by default, if the DB collation is correct, the framework itself doesn't have any issues handling them.